# JQuery .change() event triggers at different times in IE and FF

Tags: jquery, events

I'm trying to get the checked state of a checkbox after it's changed. When I click the checkbox or hit enter on my "search text box" it should toggle the checkbox's checked state then return the updated value. My example works in FF but not in IE

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/CVQjd/)

html:

```
<!--
    hit enter and it should toggle the checkbox state and return the updated value
    it works as expected in FF but not in IE
-->

<input type='text' class='txt_search' />
<input type='checkbox' class='chk_test' />
```

javascript:

```
$('.txt_search').keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == '13')
    {
        $('.chk_test').click();
    }
});


$('.chk_test').change(function(){
   var self=$(this);
   alert(self.prop('checked'));
});
```

Comment: Works fine for me in IE9, and IE8 using IE9's debugging.  In general your code is flawed in its approach.  See answer below.

Comment: Works in IE9. Not sure why not in others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I wasn't able to replicate the problem, this might be the cause of your issue:  You're calling the click event on a checkbox and then binding to the change event.  Instead, try just setting the attribute of the checkbox appropriately.  You can toggle via this method as well based on whether they entered something in the textbox:

**UPDATE**: Now works with IE8 by using `bind`.

```
$('.txt_search').keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == '13')
    {
        var chk =  $('input.chk_test');
        chk.prop('checked', !!$(this).val());
    }
});

$('.chk_test').bind('change', function(){
    var self=$(this);
    alert(self.is(':checked'));
});
```

**Fiddle proof: http://jsfiddle.net/CVQjd/6/**

Comment: if it is >jQuery 1.6 use `prop` instead of `attr`

Comment: wow. you did not change the `change` and now u have a double `!!`

Comment: @Adam T, i've tried your method and the change event function never gets triggered. Would it be bad form to also call the .change() function manually? http://jsfiddle.net/CVQjd/5/

Comment: @matt What browser are you using?  In my testing, it works just fine (calls change()).  If you really need to, you can indeed manually call change().

Comment: @Neal - What are you talking about?  I did indeed rework my code to go from simply toggling the checkbox to basing the checkbox value off of the input's content....  What's wrong with it?

Comment: @matt I updated to use `bind` instead of `change`.  IE8 seems to like that.

Comment: @Adam T, I couldn't get your example to work, i'm not sure why but i did modify it to work for me. thank you very much! http://jsfiddle.net/CVQjd/8/

Comment: @Adam T, i now see what didn't work. I had no value in the text box when hitting enter. I now see your comment that it toggles based on the input's value.

Comment: :)  Yeah.  I updated that, figuring it was more true to your objective.  Toggling based on pressing enter alone doesn't really make sense.